# PHP - Getting Channel ID after OAuth - YouTube API

Tags: php, api, oauth, youtube, youtube-data-api

Firstly, this question may sound like a duplicate but from the answers I've already seen I think the answers don't correctly fit this purpose because I do not have permission.

I'm trying to find a YouTube channel ID after they authorize their Google account.

The scopes I am using are:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

A lot of the answers refer to accessing the V3 channels api to get the channel id.

```
$channelData = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true&access_token=".$token['access']);
$channelData = json_decode($channelData, true);
```

The issue is with the scopes I'm using you cannot access this. The other questions on SO all revolve around this endpoint.

[Youtube API Retrieving Channel ID after authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704494/youtube-api-retrieving-channel-id-after-authentication)

[How to get Channel ID (YouTube API v2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934283/how-to-get-channel-id-youtube-api-v2)

[How to Get Channel id or url after Google Oauth PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120179/how-to-get-channel-id-or-url-after-google-oauth-php)

Please note I want to keep scopes to an absolute minimum. Why wouldn't this simply be possible with just the analytics API? Will I have to use another YouTube scope to find the channel id of the person who just authorised?

**The question I'm asking is**

Is there any way I can get the channel id of the user who just authorised with my current scopes? If not what is the minimum-amount-of-permission-scopes I can use to get their channel id?

Answer (score 2):

You should add `youtube.readonly` scope, plugins like `socialite` have exactly this scope hardcoded. The channel `snippet` can be got via `channels` method - [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with `part=snippet`.

Readonly scope is light enough to include it to your list. `userinfo.profile` and `yt-analytics.readonly` don't have access to channels list. This scope is the only one needed to get channel id.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]

Sorry, previously I missed `auditDetails` part. You can find YouTube API scopes here: [YouTube API scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#youtubev3)

You most certainly need that one: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube`. I'm not sure about this one: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl` because of no explanation besides "force ssl" part.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not trying to get the auditDetails part. Preferably, the snippet or id. Also, (Maybe I'm  wrong) But I believe that scope is limited to MCN/CMS holders. I will do some testing and come back! :)